# Google Oauth prompt page- add more text?

Tags: oauth, spreadsheet

I'm using GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl to send the browser to the page prompting the user to allow my application access to their Google Docs account. This all works fine, but I'd like to know if you can add some extra information to that prompt page as well as the auto-generated stuff?

Answer (score 1):

No, the only custom information that Google displays on that page is the *product name* and the *product logo* you specified in Google's [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).